# Cusotm MetaBox content not getting saved

Tags: metabox

I have added the custom meta box to my custom post types, but it is not saving content on publish or update button click.

```
/*
 * Custom book metabox
 */

// Add metabox
function author_book_meta_box_add() {
    add_meta_box( 'author-book', 'Select Book of Author', 'author_book_meta_box', 'awp-author', 'normal', 'high' );
} 
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'author_book_meta_box_add' );

// Metabox callback
function author_book_meta_box( $post ) {
    $values = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    //testing...
    print_r($values);

    $selected = isset( $values['book_meta_box_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['book_meta_box_select'][0] ) : '';
    echo "selected".$selected;

    // Add a nonce field so we can check for it later.
    //wp_nonce_field( 'author_book_meta_box_save', 'author_book_meta_box_nonce' );

    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="book_meta_box_select">Select Book: </label>
    <select name='book_meta_box_select'>
        <?php $posts=get_posts(array('post_type' => 'awp-catalogue', 'posts_per_page' => -1)); foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($post->post_title); ?>" <?php selected( $selected, $post->post_title ); ?>><?php echo esc_html($post->post_title); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    </p>
    <?php   
}
function author_book_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'author_book_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // Make sure your data is set before trying to save it
    if( isset( $_POST['book_meta_box_select'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'book_meta_box_select', esc_attr( $_POST['book_meta_box_select'] ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'author_book_meta_box_save' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're update function asks for a request parameter named `meta_box_nonce` (which is by the way a bad name) but your meta box template does not provide such a field.

It should work if you add the following line right at the end of your function `author_book_meta_box()`:

```
wp_nonce_field( 'author_book_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
```

Please consider to prefix the request parameter name `meta_box_nonce`. E.g. `your_plugin_meta_box_nonce` to avoid collisions with other plugins.